# Can spine misalignment be responsible for eye conditions?

Tags: eye, spine

Can some eye conditions be explained by a problem in a given spine vertebra? We know that the spine is connected to the nervous system, I already saw some charts connecting each vertebra to an organ and the C-2 was defined for eyes and optic nerves.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely certain what you mean by "spine misalignment", but there are certainly traumatic injuries to the cervical neck that can indirectly result in full or partial blindness. This would usually occur due to neurovascular compromise. Cervical artery dissections with subsequent cerebral infarction and homonymous hemianopia are a classic cause of visual loss after trauma.

For further reading on post-traumatic visual loss, I would refer you to [this review article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2998754/).

Comment: That's not an eye problem.

Comment: I think you can interpret “eye conditions” as anything affecting vision. I’m only trying to answer the spirit of the question.

Comment: Well it's clearly asking about chiropractic misinformation.

Comment: The word chiropractic is never used. Perhaps you mean the chart he’s referring to? That was only an example he provided to help clarify his question ; however, his question pertains to “spine vertebra” and “eye conditions”. At the very least, I’ve provided an example of how injury to cervical spine vertebra might cause blindness. Shouldn’t the voting system determine which answer has best addressed the question?

Comment: The question says spine misalignment which is typical chiropractic jargon.

Comment: Which is perhaps a term an uninformed patient overheard somewhere, believing it to be correct medical terminology. Again, the word chiropractic is not used - I believe the spirt of the question is “can spine injury cause visual disturbances” and I tried to address that. If you don’t like the answer, downvote it. I personally think your answer was unhelpful.

Comment: Then please vote accordingly. This site is only going to work if we vote.

Comment: That’s what I said four comments ago...

Comment: Great. We are in agreement! :)

Comment: Oh, and apologies if I seem a bit abrasive. Not a lot of sleep these days due to crappy chest infection!

Answer (score 1):

No, not that I'm aware.  You might see this referred to in Chiropractic charts but [chiropractic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiropractic) is an alternative non-science based system.

> Chiropractic is a form of alternative medicine mostly concerned with the diagnosis and treatment of mechanical disorders of the musculoskeletal system, especially the spine. Proponents claim that such disorders affect general health via the nervous system. These claims are not backed by any evidence.
>
> <sup>Sources cited by the wikipedia article:</sup>
> <sup>- Ernst E (May 2008). "Chiropractic: a critical evaluation". Journal of Pain and Symptom Management. 35 (5): 544–62. doi:[10.1016/j.jpainsymman.2007.07.004](https://doi.org/10.1016%2Fj.jpainsymman.2007.07.004).</sup>
> <sup>- "[Chiropractic](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/chiropractic/)". NHS Choices. 20 August 2014. Retrieved 19 September 2016.</sup>